# How can I create a Change Request or Incidents in service now using Java or Xquery or any other script?

Tags: rest, firefox, servicenow, servicenow-rest-api

I want to create change request using scripts and not from the GUI page. How can I achieve that ? Also, there is a single sign on check of my organization too.

Comment: can you please provide a little more context? you can use scheduled jobs to create Service Requests.

Comment: @Rafay - I mean I'm new to this. I can't even send a simple GET through Firefox REST client to view all incidents. This is the URL that I'm hitting -

Comment: no worries but your question is too broad its difficult to answer as is. If you can break it down like what are you trying to achieve and what is the problem you are having, in bullet points, that might help getting an answer here.

Answer (score 0):

A few options:-

Create Scripted REST API - this exposes a URL which can be called by an external system. Tricky if you are new to SN.

As @Rafay suggestions - setup a scheduled event. Check out https://community.servicenow.com/community?id=community_question&sys_id=b32c0765db9cdbc01dcaf3231f961984

Scheduled events can be scripted/reports or create templates.

Templates can create of tasks without any coding - may be easier if it meets your requirements? These are referred to as templates and can be created via the UI then scheduled to create them (e.g. A regular server patching activity).